# is_dir always returning in PHP 7

Tags: php

I upgraded from PHP 7.0.6 to 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 and I'm now unable to get the following lines of code to work.

```
protected function prepareOutput($filename, $overwrite)
{
    $directory = dirname($filename);

    if ($this->fileExists($filename)) {
        if (!$this->isFile($filename)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                'The output file \'%s\' already exists and it is a %s.',
                $filename, $this->isDir($filename) ? 'directory' : 'link'
            ));
        } elseif (false === $overwrite) {
            throw new Exceptions\FileAlreadyExistsException(sprintf(
                'The output file \'%s\' already exists.',
                $filename
            ));
        } elseif (!$this->unlink($filename)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Could not delete already existing output file \'%s\'.',
                $filename
            ));
        }
    } elseif (!$this->isDir($directory) && !$this->mkdir($directory)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf(
            'The output file\'s directory \'%s\' could not be created.',
            $directory
        ));
    }
}
 **
 * Wrapper for the "is_dir" function
 *
 * @param string $filename
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function isDir($filename)
{
    return is_dir($filename);
}

/**
 * Wrapper for the mkdir function
 *
 * @param string $pathname
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function mkdir($pathname)
{
    return mkdir($pathname, 0777, true);
}
```

`is_dir` is constantly returning false even when the folder exists. Anyone know how I can get out o this predicament? I've checked folder permissions and confirmed www:data has permissions to access the folder. When I delete the folder, it gets created then the error pops us.

Comment: What is in `$directory`

Comment: _Side Note:_ Why do you need a function called `isDir()` that only runs `is_dir()` why not just call `is_dir()` The world is short of wrappers and yuo seem to be wasting one

Comment: Ditto `mkdir()` another wasted wrapper

Comment: I thought so too but the code comes from the WKHTML to PDF wrapper for symfony found here: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle